# How to make animated counting with motion blur effect like Smartisan OS Weather App?

Tags: ios, animation

Like the Title.

The demo video is here :https://youtu.be/siiG-cBD4j4

Eager for your sincere help.Thank you indeed.

Comment: Can you show us code that you've tried?

Comment: Do you want us to write code for you? or you have tried something. You must share what you have tried.

Comment: Oops,sorry I didn't do it .And What I have idea about this is  Arkadiusz Holko's [Motion Blur](http://holko.pl/2014/07/21/motion-blur/) and dataxpress's [UICountingLabel](https://github.com/dataxpress/UICountingLabel). But any one have more efficient and easier workaround?

Comment: no,no,no,I just need a brief thought of this animation.Not the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your date changing code inside this animation block. You get the same motion blur effect:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0
         usingSpringWithDamping:0.8
          initialSpringVelocity:0.6
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{

                         [self.view.superview layoutIfNeeded];
;

    } completion:nil];
```